# como cambiar color de un Html.ActionLink

Tags: c#, css, razor

```
<div class="row">
@foreach(var comicBook in Model)
{
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h4>@Html.ActionLink(comicBook.DisplayText, "Detail", new { id = comicBook.Id })</h4>
        <a href="@Url.Action("Detail", new { id = comicBook.Id})">
            <img src="/Images/@comicBook.CoverImageFileName"
                 alt="@comicBook.DisplayText"
                 class="img-responsive" />
        </a>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haz lo siguiente:

```
Html.ActionLink("My Link", "MyAction", null, new { @class = "my-class" })
```

Luego en **CSS** agregar lo siguiente o puedes ponerlo entre `<style>` dentro de tu **html**

```
a.my-class { color: #333333 }
a.my-class:active { color: #666666 }
a.my-class:link { color: #999999 }
a.my-class:visited { color: #CCCCCC }
```

Comment: <h4>@Html.ActionLink(comicBook.DisplayText, "Detail", new { id = comicBook.Id })</h4> la parte new { id = comicBook.Id } es muy importante no vi que en tu opcion pueda poner mis id de forma dinamica, sugieres borrarla? pues en mi inventario cada comic tiene un id distinto :(

Comment: No, al contrario es mucho mejor si lo representas con el id

Comment: como seria mi codigo entonces?

Comment: Html.ActionLink("My Link", "MyAction", null, new { id = "my-Id", @class = "my-class"})

Comment: no me funciona, sera porque estoy usando bootstrap? es la primera vez que lo implemento

Comment: <h4>@Html.ActionLink(comicBook.DisplayText, "Detail",null, new { id = comicBook.Id, @class = "links" })</h4>  lo puse asi

Comment: tu usas bootstrap? disculpa que te siga molestando